# Javascript Image Gallery

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a "slideshow" using html and JavaScript. I want the image to change every time i press on a button that i set up(see code below). I've checked my code several times and i could not find the problem as to how the image wont change when i click the input button. Here's what i have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var imgArray ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg", "6.jpg", "7.jpg"];
var capArray ["Processor", "Motherboard", "Computer Case", "RAM", "Graphics Card", "Hard Drive" "Optical Drive"];

var imgIndex = imgArray.length -1;

function showImage(index) 
{
    document.getElementById('imgGallery').src       = imgArray[index];
    document.getElementById('imgGallery').alt       = capArray[index];
    document.getElementById('imgGallery').title     = capArray[index];
    document.getElementById('imgCaption').innerHTML = capArray[index];
}
function nextImage() 
{
    imgIndex++;
    imgIndex = imgIndex % imgArray.length;
    showImage(imgIndex);
}
function prevImage() 
{
 imgIndex--;
 if (imgIndex < 0) { imgIndex = imgArray.length  -1; }
 imgIndex = iIndex % imgArray.length;
 showImage(imgIndex);
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="nextImage();">
<div>
<div>
    Computer Parts
</div>
<img id="imgGallery"  alt="Processor" src="images/1.jpg" title="Processor" />
        <div id="imgCaption">
            Processor
        </div>
<br />
<input type="button" value="<" onclick="prevImage();"> </input>
<input type="button" value=">" onclick="nextImage();"> </input>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like your src value needs 'images/' in front of it.

Comment: Could you please explain this a little bit more? Thanks

Comment: Your img tag in your HTML has src="images/1.jpg". When you add the next image in nextImage, it calls showImage which changes the source to src="2.jpg". Assuming that all of your images are in the same place (the images directory), image 2 will be not found.

Comment: That does make a lot of sense, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had quite a few random errors. The array's having no `=`, a missing comma, and a misspelled variable. Here is a working version of your code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var imgArray = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg", "6.jpg", "7.jpg"];
var capArray = ["Processor", "Motherboard", "Computer Case", "RAM", "Graphics Card", "Hard Drive", "Optical Drive"];

var imgIndex = imgArray.length -1;

function showImage(index) 
{
    document.getElementById('imgGallery').src       = imgArray[index];
    document.getElementById('imgGallery').alt       = capArray[index];
    document.getElementById('imgGallery').title     = capArray[index];
    document.getElementById('imgCaption').innerHTML = capArray[index];
}
function nextImage() 
{
    imgIndex++;
    imgIndex = imgIndex % imgArray.length;
    showImage(imgIndex);
}
function prevImage() 
{
 imgIndex--;
 if (imgIndex < 0) { imgIndex = imgArray.length  -1; }
 imgIndex = imgIndex % imgArray.length;
 showImage(imgIndex);
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="nextImage();">
<div>
<div>
    Computer Parts
</div>
<img id="imgGallery"  alt="Processor" src="images/1.jpg" title="Processor" />
        <div id="imgCaption">
            Processor
        </div>
<br />
<input type="button" value="<" onclick="prevImage();"> </input>
<input type="button" value=">" onclick="nextImage();"> </input>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I made the changes, but still no luck. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

Check your JavaScript syntax in the Console. You were missing the assignment (equals character) on your array variables. Also missing a comma in the second array. This is what you want:

```
var imgArray = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg", "6.jpg", "7.jpg"];
var capArray = ["Processor", "Motherboard", "Computer Case", "RAM", "Graphics Card", "Hard Drive", "Optical Drive"];
```

Comment: Thanks! The nextImage() input is working, but no luck for prevImage().

Comment: Actually scratch that, i found the error. thanks again!

Comment: Another typo. On Line 27, change it to this: imgIndex = imgIndex % imgArray.length;

Comment: Good deal. Glad you got it.

Comment: @ChuckyC what was the problem? Why it was throwing nextImage() not defined?

Comment: In your original you had, imgIndex = iIndex % imgArray.length; iIndex was the typo. The JS engine read that as an undefined variable, which it was. So, it had to be changed.